# Your app is currently targeted at API level 31, but should have a minimum API level of 33. -> But API Level 33 is definitely used

Tags: android, google-developers-console, android-api-levels

I am developing a .net app for the google PlayStore and have run across a problem.
The targeted Android Framework is 13.0 with API level 33.
But every time I upload it to the release part it gives me this error:

> Your app is currently targeted at API level 31, but should have a minimum API level of 33.

I tried changing from Visual Studio 2022 to Android Studio, from deployment on my phone (api 31) to an emulator (api 33) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

That complaint means the targetSDKVersion in your manifest isn't high enough.  This has nothing to do with what IDE you use or what version of Android is running on the device.  You can make it work for personal use with a targetSDKVersion too low, but the Play Store will not accept it.

Comment: The manifest has the correct version and it still shows up.